# Baire category of subset $\mathbb{R} \setminus B$ with lebesgue zero measure $B$

Tags: functional-analysis, lebesgue-measure, baire-category

Let $\mathbb{Q}=\{ q_i\}^{\infty}_{i=1}$.

Let $I_{ij} = \left(q_i - \delta_{ij}, q_i + \delta_{ij}\right)$, $\delta_{ij}=2^{-i-j-1}$ for all $i,j \geq 1$ be an open interval. 
For every $j\geq1$, let $G_{j} = \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} I_{ij}$, and let $B = \bigcap\limits_{j\geq1}^{\infty}G_{j}$.

I want to show that $B$ is a set of Lebesgue measure zero and $\mathbb{R}\setminus B$ is first category Baire set in $\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can estimate the measure of $G_j$ pretty easily. Then apply continuity of the measure for $B$.

Every $G_j$ is dense (why?) and open (why?), so the other statement follows from the fact that the complement of an open dense subset is closed and nowhere dense. So $\mathbb{R} \setminus B$ is the countable union of such sets (de Morgan).

Comment: Thanks for the first part, now i understand how to deal with it. 
But can you show why $G_j$ is dense? (open just because union open?)

Comment: Yes, $G_j$ is open since it is a union of open intervals. As to density, what's a really nice set you know is contained in $G_j$?

Comment: it is $ \mathbb{Q}$ right? What about completeness. How we use it?

Comment: Completeness is not really used. I'll edit.